# How to assert whether page is displayed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to verify whether home page is displayed before executing other test cases on the website.

```
Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), “Title of webpage”, "Home page is not opened ");
```

However above assert is passed, when HTML is displayed as below. I would like to pass only when the actual website is loaded including all images. Please help me with it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is :

```
assertEquals(expected, actual)
```

use the following way:

```
assertEquals(expected title, driver.gettitle());
```

Comment: Hi @Ganesh - This assertion is passed when HTML is loaded in browser as shown in screenshot(Actual page is not loaded in browser, Please see screenshot).